# to get value from String variable containing a decimal number representing a value of about 64 gigabyte

Tags: c++, string, c++builder, c++builder-xe4

I have a question in conversion of String into value.

Following is the sample code I tried.

I am trying this on C++ Builder XE4.

```
String strSize = L"64420392960"; // 64GB

size_t size;

size = strSize.ToDouble(); // returns 4290850816

char *end_ptr;
size = strtol(AnsiString(strSize).c_str(), &end_ptr, 10); // returns 0
```

Both of ToDouble() and strtol() didn't work.

I understand that strtol didn't work because long type is up to 4.3GB.

Are there any function in C++ Builder XE4, with which I can convert the strSize into size_t value when I treat 64GB or several hundreds of GB (e.g. 500GB)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a 64GB string, which would be a string that's 64 gigabytes in size. You have a string containing a decimal number representing a value of about 64 gig.

The standard function you're looking for is `strtoll`, which returns a `long long` result. It's been a standard C function since the 1999 standard, and if I'm not mistaken was added to the C++ standard as of 2011.

(The question is whether C++ Builder XE4 supports `strtoll`.)

If `size_t` on your system is only 32 bits, there's no way to get a `size_t` value that big. If it's 64 bits, `strtoll` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much. The strtoll function is supported C++ Builder XE4. So I will use strtoll. Also I changed the type of size into long long. Then it worked. I appreciate.

Comment: Thank you also for correction of my English. I changed the title of this question. I hope this change will reduce confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the VCL `String` object (which is apparently an alias for the VCL <strike>`AnsiString`</strike> `UnicodeString` class) returns a `double` with the value 64420392960.0 which gets converted into an integral type but the `size_t` is a 32-bit unsigned type so it keeps only the lower 32 bits of the value.

Instead of a type `size_t` try an `unsigned long long` or plain old `long long` if your toolchain supports it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't recognize that size_t is 32-bit unsigned type. I will use long long type. So, using ToDouble() then static_cast to long long may work, right?

Comment: The cast shouldn't be needed.

Comment: @sevenOfNine: The size of `size_t` may be either 32 or 64 bits, depending on the system. (Other sizes are permitted, but those are the most common.)

Comment: In XE4, `String` is an alias for `UnicodeString`, not `AnsiString`, and has been so since C++Builder 2009.

Comment: @Keith Thompson: Thank you for your comment. I will check size_t on different system.

Answer (score 1):

Other people have explained why your original code does not work.  There is another alternative: use `__int64` instead of `long long`.  The VCL has support for `__int64`, eg:

```
String strSize = L"64420392960";
__int64 size = StrToInt64(strSize);
```

Don't use `double` unless you really need floating-point precision.

Comment: Thank you very much. __int64 is simpler than "long long" making code clearer. Also, I agree not to use double unless I have the reason to do that.